# Farewell neo4j webadmin

Tags: graph, neo4j, visualization

1. Is there a specific reason that `webadmin` was deprecated and then finally removed in `2.3.0`? Was its presence impeding something?
2. I'm used to using the `webadmin` visualisation to browse around nodes and relationships. This is not working in the `browser` visualisation as nodes are displayed without a hint of its relationships. Only if another neighbouring node is display, does the relationship between them get displayed. (See attached screenshots) So, is there a way to casually browse around the nodes, just to see what's there? (I used to be able to just enter a single node ID and start browsing.)
3. (Bonus question) Can you please bring webadmin back, just for a little while longer? Its loss gives me yet another learning curve I really don't need right now.

[image: Neo4j webadmin]
[image: Neo4j browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webadmin endpoint has been inadvertently removed in 2.3RC1, this also cause that you can not get the schema back when issuing the :schema command, check here :

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5665

This has been fixed in 2.3.0GA

Answer (score 2):

Webadmin has been deprecated in Neo4j 2.3.0, but is still available. There is a banner that appears first with a message about the deprecation, but once that is closed webadmin is still there.

Webadmin will only be removed when it has been obviated by the capabilities of Neo4j Browser. For that, I appreciate the feedback about the aspects of webadmin which you find valuable. We'll take that into account as we work to improve Neo4j Browser.

Best,
Andreas

Comment: I was using webadmin in the 2.3.0 Milestones, but as soon as I moved to RC1, I found the /webadmin URL returned a blank screen ....

Comment: Yes an inadvertent removal of the endpoints in RC1 was introduced. This is fixed in 2.3.0 final

Comment: Except we can't use 2.3.0 because of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Guess we'll have to wait for 2.3.1 ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351632/cause-of-neo4j-indexoutofboundsexception-on-getrelationships-again )

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen - if you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks I added an answer